# Server not allowing multiple connections to Internet Download Manager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download, iis-8, download-manager

I have written a code for enabling multiple connection download(Range-Requests) through Internet Download Manager and it works fine in my local system(it is able to create multiple connections and download a file.) but it's not able to create more than one connection in my server (Windows 2012 R2).

Also, when I keep a file on download and try to open another webpage of my application, it shows loading and does not open(until I cancel the download or let the download to complete.)

Below is my downloader code:

```
public ActionResult getFile()
    {
        System.IO.FileStream iStream = null;
        var response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        var request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
        // Buffer to read 10K bytes in chunk:
        byte[] buffer = new Byte[10000];
        int length1;
        long dataToRead;
        try
        {
            //File path.
            string finalPath = @"C:\myfiles\abc.txt"; 
            long size, start, end, length, fp = 0;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(finalPath))
            {
                size = new System.IO.FileInfo(finalPath).Length;
                start = 0;
                end = size - 1;
                length = size;
                response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "0-" + size);
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Headers["Range"])) 
                {
                    long anotherStart = start;
                    long anotherEnd = end;
                    string[] arr_split = request.Headers["Range"].Split(new char[] { Convert.ToChar("=") });
                    string range = arr_split[1];

                    // Make sure the client hasn't sent us a multibyte range
                    if (range.IndexOf(",") > -1)
                    {
                        // (?) Shoud this be issued here, or should the first
                        // range be used? Or should the header be ignored and
                        // we output the whole content?
                        response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + size);
                        throw new HttpException(416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable");

                    }

                    // If the range starts with an '-' we start from the beginning
                    // If not, we forward the file pointer
                    // And make sure to get the end byte if spesified
                    if (range.StartsWith("-"))
                    {
                        // The n-number of the last bytes is requested
                        anotherStart = size - Convert.ToInt64(range.Substring(1));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        arr_split = range.Split(new char[] { Convert.ToChar("-") });
                        anotherStart = Convert.ToInt64(arr_split[0]);
                        long temp = 0;
                        anotherEnd = (arr_split.Length > 1 && Int64.TryParse(arr_split[1].ToString(), out temp)) ? Convert.ToInt64(arr_split[1]) : size;
                    }
                    /* Check the range and make sure it's treated according to the specs.
                     * http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
                     */
                    // End bytes can not be larger than $end.
                    anotherEnd = (anotherEnd > end) ? end : anotherEnd;
                    // Validate the requested range and return an error if it's not correct.
                    if (anotherStart > anotherEnd || anotherStart > size - 1 || anotherEnd >= size)
                    {

                        response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + size);
                        throw new HttpException(416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable");
                    }
                    start = anotherStart;
                    end = anotherEnd;
                    fp = reader.BaseStream.Seek(start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    length = end - start + 1; // Calculate new content length
                    response.StatusCode = 206;
                }
            }

            var fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(finalPath);
            var fileNameUrlEncoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName1, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            // Notify the client the byte range we'll be outputting
            response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" +
                                                            fileNameUrlEncoded.Replace("+", "%20"));

            response.AddHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + size);
            response.AddHeader("Content-Length", length.ToString());



            //response.WriteFile(finalPath, fp, length);
            //response.End();
            //As WriteFile() method does not work for huge files, thus using
            //Chunk downloading below.


            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(finalPath);

            iStream = new FileStream(finalPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                        System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read,4096,true);
            // Total bytes to read:
            dataToRead = length;
            iStream.Position = start;

            while (dataToRead > 0)
            {

                // Verify that the client is connected.
                if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                // Read the data in buffer.
                length1 = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);

                // Write the data to the current output stream.
                Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length1);

                // Flush the data to the HTML output.
                Response.Flush();
                buffer = new Byte[10000];
                dataToRead = dataToRead - length1;
                }
                else
                {
                //prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
                    dataToRead = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "error: " + e.Message;
            return View();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (iStream != null)
            {
                //Close the file.
                iStream.Close();
            }
            response.Close();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I am suspecting some server configuration issues that is causing the above issue. Can anyone help me to know what configuration changes might cause this issue.

Thanks in Advance.